# How should i solve counting problem in my divisor program C++

Tags: c++, count, counting

hi guys i recently started learning C++ and today i got a problem with counting divisors in this program
i want my program to count the number of divisors exactly but the output show weird numbers :/

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    int Lowest;
    int Highest;
    int count = 0;

    cout << "Enter The Lowest Number Of Series: ";
    cin >> Lowest;
    cout << "Enter The Highest Number Of Series: ";
    cin >> Highest;

    cout << "\n Number -> Divisors ((count)) \n";

    for (int i = Lowest; i <= Highest; i++)
    {
        cout << " " << i << " ->";
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0)
            {
                count++;                                                              // WTF 
                cout << " " << j;
            }
        }
        cout << " (( count:" << count << " )) " << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

for example out put for Lower=1 to Highest=10 is like this:

```
Enter The Lowest Number Of Series: 1
Enter The Highest Number Of Series: 10

Number -> Divisors ((count))
 1 -> 1 (( count:1 ))
 2 -> 1 2 (( count:3 ))
 3 -> 1 3 (( count:5 ))
 4 -> 1 2 4 (( count:8 ))
 5 -> 1 5 (( count:10 ))
 6 -> 1 2 3 6 (( count:14 ))
 7 -> 1 7 (( count:16 ))
 8 -> 1 2 4 8 (( count:20 ))
 9 -> 1 3 9 (( count:23 ))
 10 -> 1 2 5 10 (( count:27 ))
```

Do you guys have any idea What is Wrong?

Comment: Please don't add multiple language tags. C and C++ are different languages and both tags are rarely appropriate for a question.

Comment: You forgot to reset `count` to 0 before executing the inner loop each time.

Comment: This is a good opportunity to learn to use your debugger.  You should be able to step through your code line-by-line and inspect the values of any suspicious variables (such as `count`) at each step to figure out what is happening.

Comment: ah thanks dude i need to pay more attention while i'm coding :(

Comment: And pay even more attention while debugging. To be a successful programmer you have to learn how to make good use of a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by @cigien's comment, your `count` variable never gets reset to zero so it just keeps counting up. Reset it between each iteration of the outer loop. Better still, move the declaration to the closest place where it's used:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;  // only using what you need

int main()
{
    int Lowest;
    int Highest;

    cout << "Enter The Lowest Number Of Series: ";
    cin >> Lowest;
    cout << "Enter The Highest Number Of Series: ";
    cin >> Highest;

    cout << "\n Number -> Divisors ((count)) \n";

    for (int i = Lowest; i <= Highest; i++)
    {
        int count = 0;  // <-- initialize to zero on every pass
        cout << " " << i << " ->";
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0)
            {
                count++;
                cout << " " << j;
            }
        }
        cout << " (( count:" << count << " )) \n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```